# Python confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

I have a problem with the evaluation of clusters result.

I have 3 lists:

```
# 10 objects in my corpus
TOT = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

# .... clustering into k=5 clusters

# For each automatic cluster:

    # Objects with ID 2 and 8 are stored into this
    predicted = [2,8]

    # For each cluster in the ground truth:  
        true = [2,4,9]

        # computes TP, FP, TN, FN
        A = set(docs_in_cluster)
        B = set(constraints)

        TP = list(A & B)
        FP = list(A - (A & B))
        TN = list((TOT - A) & (TOT - B))
        FN = list(B - A)
```

My question is: Can I compute TP, FP, TN, FN for each cluster? Does it make sense?

**EDIT: Reproducible code**

Short story:

I'm doing NLP, I have a corpus of 9k document that I have processed with Gensim's Word2Vec, extracted the vectors, and computed a "document vector" for each document. After that, I have computed the cosine similarity between document vectors obtaining a 9k x 9k matrix.

Finally, using this matrix I have run KMeans and Hierarchical Clustering.

Let's consider the outputs from HAC with 14 clusters:

```
id    label
 0        1
 1        8
     ....
9k       12
```

Now the problem is: How can I evaluate the quality of my clusters? 
My professor have read 100 of these 9k documents and has created some 'clusters' saying: "ok this document talks about: `label1`" or "ok this other talks about both `label2` and `label3`.

Notice that labels provided by my professor are completely unrelated to the clustering process, and are just a summary of the topic, but the number is the same (in this example =14).

**The code**

I have two dataframes, the one above from HAC clustering and the one of 100 documents from my professors, that looks like:
(with the example made before)

**GT**

```
id    label1    label2    label3    ....    label14
 5         1         0         0                 0
34         0         1         1                 0
      ...........................
```

And finally, my code does this:

```
 # since I have labels only for 100 of my 9k documents
 indexes = list(map(int, ground_truth['id'].values.tolist()))
 reduced_df = clusters.loc[clusters['id'].isin(indexes), :]

 # now reduced_df contains only the documents that have been read by my prof
 TOT = set(reduced_df['id'].values.tolist())

 for each cluster from HAC
    doc_in_this_cluster = [ .... ]

    for each cluster from GT
       doc_in_this_label = [ ... ]

        A = set(doc_in_this_cluster )
        B = set(doc_in_this_label )

        TP = list(A & B)
        FP = list(A - (A & B))
        TN = list((TOT - A) & (TOT - B))
        FN = list(B - A)
```

And the code:

```
indexes = list(map(int, self.ground_truth['id'].values.tolist()))
    # reduce clusters_file matching only manually analyzed documents:  -------->   TOT
    reduced_df = self.clusters.loc[self.clusters['id'].isin(indexes), :]

    TOT = set(reduced_df['id'].values.tolist())

    clusters_groups = reduced_df.groupby('label')

    for label, df_group in clusters_groups:
        docs_in_cluster = df_group['id'].values.tolist()

        row = []
        for col in self.ground_truth.columns[1:]:
            constraints = list(
                map(int, self.ground_truth.loc[self.ground_truth[col] == 1, 'id'].values.tolist())
            )

            A = set(docs_in_cluster)
            B = set(constraints)

            TP = list(A & B)
            FP = list(A - (A & B))
            TN = list((TOT - A) & (TOT - B))
            FN = list(B - A)

            print(f"HAC Cluster: {label} - GT Label: {col}")
            print(TP, FP, TN, FN)
```

Comment: You will have to implement these functions yourself

Comment: Your confusion matrix succeeded in confusing me. You might need to provide some more context, ideally a [mre] that can be run and explain whats wrong. You are commenting about "corpus" - are you doing natural language processing via ML?

Comment: I will edit the first message with all these information

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to implement set operations. You can try the following functions to solve your case:

```py
def setSubtract(A,B):
    C=[]
    for i in A:
        if i in B:
            pass
        else:
            C.append(i)
    return C

def setIntersection(A,B):
    C=[]
    for i in A:
        if i in B:
            C.append(i)
    return C

TOT = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[2,3]
print("A&B",setIntersection(A,B))
print("TOT-B",setSubtract(TOT,B))
```

Output:

```py
A&B [2, 3]
TOT-B [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```